# Prove function is differentiable by definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have this function:

$f(x,y)=\left ( sin(x)y,e^{xy} \right)$

I need to prove this function is differentiable (and find the derivative) using the formal definition. However, I wasn't able to prove this for the "second function": $e^{xy}$. I started with writing:

$f(\vec{x}+\vec{h})-f(\vec{x})=e^{(x+h_{1})(y+h_{2})}-e^{xy}$.

I know the Jacobian is:
$\begin{pmatrix}
ye^{xy} & xe^{xy}
\end{pmatrix}$, so I should reach something like: $e^{(x+h_{1})(y+h_{2})}-e^{xy}=ye^{xy}h_{1}+xe^{xy}h_{2}+o(\vec{h})$, but I have know idea how to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note $e^{(x+h_1)(y+h_2)}=e^{xy}e^{h_1y+h_2x+h_1h_2}$. Then you can use Taylor expansion to get your required result.

Comment: remember that any function that is continuous and smooth on some interval $I$ is necessarily differentiable on $I$. Also recall that for any two functions $f$ and $g$, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on some interval $I$, then $f \cdot g$ is continuous on $I$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment:
\begin{align}
e^{(x+h_1)(y+h_2)}-e^{xy}&=e^{xy}(e^{h_1y+h_2x+h_1h_2}-1) \\\\
&=e^{xy}(1+h_1y+h_2x+O(h_1h_2)-1)\\\\&=ye^{xy}h_1+xe^{xy}h_2+O(h_1h_2)\end{align}